# An easier way of setting nested properties values in Grpc generated java code

Tags: java, grpc, protobuff.net

We are using Grpc with our java apps and we have a nested object defined in protobuff.

example of the proto:

```
message Person {
  string name = 1;
  Child child = 2; 
}

message Child {
  string name = 1;
  Hobby hobbies = 2;
}

message Hobby {
  string name = 1;
  string reason = 2;
}
```

When I want to update the reason for the child's hobby I have to do something like:

```
person.toBuilder()
.setChild(
    person.getChild.toBuilder()
        .setHobby(
            person.getChild().getHobby().toBuilder()
                .setReason("new reason")
                .build()
        )
        .build()
)
.build()
```

The code above is not the nicest and my question is if there is any better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

```
Person.Builder builder = person.toBuilder();
builder.getChildBuilder().getHobbyBuilder().setReason("new reason");
Person personWithUpdatedReason = builder.build();
```

Details:
Better way is subjective, what are you expectations?
I believe, something along the lines of:

```
person.getChild().getHobby().setReason("new reason");
```

If that's the case, you'd want the object to be mutable, which, depending upon the context, may not be a good thing.

Another example:

```
Hobby newHobby = person.getChild().getHobby().toBuilder().setReason("new reason").build();
Child newChild = person.getChild().toBuilder().setHobby(newHobby).toBuild();
Person newPerson = person.toBuilder().setChild(newChild).toBuild();

return newPerson;
```

This is better if only you don't like your code to have multi-level nesting.

Unfortunately, I don't think I helped you, rather interested to know what you/others think of this.

I read a bit more on this, and the official docs do suggest a better way:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated?csw=1#sub-builders

So you can write you code something like this:

```
Person.Builder builder = person.toBuilder();
builder.getChildBuilder().getHobbyBuilder().setReason("new reason");
Person personWithUpdatedReason = builder.build();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you